# JS/ How to search with input by firstname and lastname but also work if i type space after firstname

Tags: javascript, html, search

```
let input = document.getElementById('searchInput')
let searchField = document.getElementById('searchField')

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const string = e.target.value
const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
if (string != '') {
if (user.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(string) || user.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(string)) {
 return user
 } else {
            searchField.innerHTML = ''
        }
    } else {
        searchField.innerHTML = ''
    }
})
filteredUsers.map(user => {
    personImg = user.picture.thumbnail
    person = user.name.first + ' ' + user.name.last
    searchField.innerHTML += `<li class="list-group-item"><img src='${personImg}'>${person}</li>`

})})
```

I have managed to write a searching function which returns a fetched user picture, first name and last name. Searching is by first and last name. However after entering first name and if i have multiple options displayed, if i press space to enter a last name of my choice it breaks. How do i implement it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
const string = e.target.value
if (user.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(string) || user.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(string)) {
```

With this:

```
const q1 = e.target.value.split(' ')[0]
const q2 = e.target.value.split(' ')[1]
if (user.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(q1) && (!q2 || user.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(q2))) {}
```

This way, it split `John Doe` to `John` and `Doe` and search `John` in the first names and `Doe` in the last names. (`!q2 ||` is for when the search query just contains the first name.)

Here is more completed answer:

```
// mock user data
let user = {name: {first: 'John', last: 'Doe'}}
// mock event
let e = {target: {value: 'John D'}}
// searched queries
const q1 = e.target.value.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0]
const q2 = e.target.value.toLowerCase().split(' ')[1]
let matched = false;
const first = user.name.first.toLowerCase();
const last = user.name.last.toLowerCase();
if(!q2){
  // when we entered just `John`,
  // then we should match all first names or last names containing `John`
  if(first.includes(q1) || last.includes(q1)) matched = true;
}else{
  // when we entered just `John D`, first name should match `John` and last name should match `D`.
  if(first.includes(q1) && last.includes(q2)) matched = true;
}
if (matched) {}
```

Also If the names may have more chunks (like: `John Doe Smith`), you can split the search string into chunks, and search them inside of names, and sort the results. something like :

```
let foundUser = undefined;
e.target.value.split(' ').forEach(q => {
  if (user.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(q) || 
      user.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(q)) {
        foundUser = user;
  }
})
if(foundUser){...}else{...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not managed to make the second method work, probably cause I'm too confused with syntax still. Like I still need to map or filter users and inside it add forEach. Anyways, the first method works, but after entering first name, space and starting to type in the last name, filtered user that was found by first name stays on top of the list, but then it starts to search for matches of last names additionally. How would I prevent that?

Comment: @eyyMinda No problem. based on the logic behind the first one, if you search for `John K`, it matches the `John Doe` and also `John Kerry`. if it's not expected result, then you can change `||` to `&&`. this way, it ensures that both first names and last names are matched. (I updated the answer.) (Note that you should also accept the empty `q2`. like when search is : `John` (`q2` is empty), we should accept it.) (i also added `!q2 || ` in the answer.)

Comment: @eyyMinda No problem. i added a more detailed answer, to show `John Doe` when we search for `Doe`. Also you need to add `.toLowerCase()` to the searched string. Also consider upvoting/accepting the answers, by pressing the check-mark next to the answer. (this way, other people see that the question is answered, in the list of questions. also stack-overflow rewards the accepted answer by reputation.)